# Use eclipse IDE for Java On Graphic card

Tags: java, windows, gpu

Is there any way to run Eclipse through my GPU for faster results because my processor is too slow

Comment: I don't think Java comes with support for your GPU's architecture.

Comment: i have Nvidia Geforce 210.Can i use CUDA for java programming? i am new to java.have been usiing eclipse.

Comment: CUDA programs are written in a specialized dialect of C or C++, not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i use CUDA for java programming?

Yes you can use your GPU, not to run your whole Java program but you can speed up your graphics.  I suggest trying OpenCL or OpenCV, but the easiest to use might be lwjgl which is what Minecraft uses.  To get started I suggest looking at jMonkeyEngine which is easier to start with.

> i have Nvidia Geforce 210

I don't think you can buy a model that slow any more, I don't think it's going to help you much.

It's a 16 core 1.4 GHz processor. Unless you are doing graphics work, your "slow" CPU is likely to be faster.

NOTE; Most development machines run slowly because they don't have enough

- memory
- disk performance.

Just adding more memory and  a cheap SSD might make all the difference you need.

Comment: LWJGL doesn't let you run Java on a GPU, it just lets Java programs submit work to a GPU.  You still have to write the OpenGL shaders, OpenCL kernels, etc. in their respective specialized languages.

Comment: @Wyzard Agree, I suspect the OP's problem is not CPU anyway.

Answer (score 5):

A GPU is not a general-purpose processor and cannot run programs written in general-purpose languages like Java.  You can run programs on a GPU using [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA), but they have to be written in a specialized language that's designed for the sort of parallel-computation environment that a GPU provides.

Also, GPUs don't just magically make things faster.  An individual thread on a GPU runs much slower than it would on a typical CPU; the difference is that a GPU can run hundreds or thousands of threads simultaneously, instead of the four or so that a CPU can handle.  This design works well for [embarrassingly-parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) tasks that can actually be divided up into hundreds or thousands of concurrent threads, but many algorithms can't be parallelized like that, and thus wouldn't benefit from running on a GPU.